# routes.rb mapping controller name creating problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rake

I am trying to map all request coming with the name of /affil/ to /affiliate/
Affiliate is my controller name. 
So any request coming like /affil/index/ should be mapped to /affiliate/index/ similarly for other functions
so for that i have tried in routes.rb

```
match '/affil/' => '/affiliate/', via: [:get, :post]
```

but this is giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of solving such issue is:-
match 'affil/:action' => 'affiliate#action', via: [:get, :post]

This solution will always work for all the action present in controller